# Lyapunov Function and $\omega$-limit sets

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I will ask you about a particular equation but what I would really enjoy is an (if possible, comprehensive) answer to the following question : How can we, using a Lyapunov function, study the $\omega$-limit set of a certain (possibly non-linear) ordinary differential equation. The only way I know is using LaSalle Principle and Poincaré-Bendixson theorem (or some consequences of it). I will present the problem in question that I would like to serve as an exemple for more detailed answers. If nobody has time or patience for such an answer, I would appreciate a LOT just to see some solution for this particular problem, since I haven't seen none.
The equation is as usual $\frac{d}{dt}x=F(x)$, where $F(x,y)=(y,-ax-bx^{2}-cy)$, with $a,b,c$ positive constants. I want to describe the $\omega$-limit set of $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^{2}}$. The suggestion on this exercise is to compute a Lyapunov function of the form : $Ax^{2}+Bx^{4}+Cy^{2}$, with $A,B,C$ positive constants.
Thank you so much in advance :)